# How do I check "unchanged" files while crawling?

Tags: python, scala, web-crawler

I'm trying to build a crawler that indexes .deb files and also parses the internals and extracts some meta information.

Now, I want to do this as cheaply as possible - but also as frequently as possible (maybe once every 5-6 hours). So I want to make sure I dont download files that are unchanged.

Maybe I'm missing something here, but how do I check that a file is unchanged without downloading it ?

Comment: Make a HEAD request for the .deb files, and see what headers are returned. You might get a `Last-Modified` or similar - worth a try?

Answer (score 1):

Download the meta data (directory listing) which will give you the timestamp, file size etc. Use that to determine if the file has changed. You can also check MD5 hash if available. Once you are sure the file has changed, you can mark it for download.

A similar strategy is used by web browsers to determine if an asset has changed. Even email clients use similar strategy, especially on hand held devices. They first download only the mail header. If  user wants to read the mail, then body is downloaded.